# soapui random delay

Tags: soapui

How to make a random delay between test steps with soapUI?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add Groovy Script step before each Request step with the next code that adds 0-9 seconds delay:

```
sleep(new Random().nextInt(10) * 1000)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! I was searching a while.. the SOAP UI docu only stats how to add a delay for the client side (http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/controlling-flow.html)

Comment: In Jenkinsfile, I had to drop `* 1000` (`sleep` accepts seconds, not milliseconds).

Answer (score 4):

Exactly what you're looking for is the following.

1. Add a **Delay** test step.
2. Instead of filling a fixed number i.e. 500ms, use this expresion

   ${=(int)(Math.random()*10000)}

And change the 10000 with the multiplier that best suits your test.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to add Delay step (which is inbuilt step for soapui pro) and mention the time in ms(milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

Inside delay test step specify 
${=5000 + 5000*Math.random()}
Which delay your request for 5s-10s.

Or you can use groovy script before each request.

Or you can run a groovy snippet to run before each test step execute. Check events.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, it should be a "**Load Test**" with a defined strategy of requests :

```
Thread : is it concurrent tests or not (1) ?
Strategy : "Simple" in your case
Test Delay : the delay between each test run in milliseconds
Random : the relative amount of randomization for delay
         (0 = no random, 1 = all random)
```

Comment: I don't think that the thread opener is talking about load tests but functional tests.

Comment: maybe but it's not clear in 10 words, so it would be one solution on this subject